# Редирект 301 для адресов страниц в верхнем регистре на нижний регистр

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Есть сайт на WordPress. При сканировании страниц, показало ошибку:

> Проверяются заведомо некорректные адреса, а также адреса страниц в
>   другом регистре. Ответом на ошибочные адреса должен быть 404 или 410.
>   С адресов в неверном регистре должны стоять 301 редиректы на адреса в
>   верном регистре.

Например: `site.ru/USLUGI/` или `site.ru/uslugi/POKRASKA/avtomobiley/`
Можно ли настроить автоматический редирект, который будет срабатывать только на страницах с данной проблемой, а нормальные URL с нижним регистром обходил стороной?

Comment: https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-uppercase-lowercase/

Comment: Какой у вас сервер? Apache, nginx?

Comment: @WPPunk  используется связка - Niginx и Apache. Nginx обрабатывает статический контент, и проксирует запросы к Apache, для обработки динамического контента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать готовые плагины типа https://wordpress.org/plugins/lh-force-lowercase-urls/
Но лучше бы изменить регистр адресов.